# Is it a memory leak in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have created simple app with two acitivities, in both activities there a button which links to another activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.two);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (intent != null) intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(Two.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In both activity there is same code. When i press Button and press Cause GC in DDMS, allocated is always growing by 25kb is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a *memory leak* but poor concept. What you are doing is putting activities on the stack which, of course, takes up more and more memory. If you want to just open the *previous* activity (thus not creating a new one each time you call `startActivity(...)`), use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Two.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to know more about tasks and the back stack, visit [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).